# No module named "...." while importing module from another module

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python, I have a folder structure as:

```
|myproject
    |src 
       |info
           |__init__.py
           |information.py

       |call 
           |__init__.py
           |call_info.py
```

Code:

**information.py**

```
class myinfo:


    def my_acadmics(self):

        print('Masters')


    def my_earning(self, first, second):

        return first+second


    def my_address(self,addr):

        return addr
```

**call_info.py**

```
from src.info.information import myinfo
obj = myinfo()

print(obj.my_acadmics())
```

**Error:**

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

I am running it from the src folder.

Comment: Doesn't look like there *is* any module named `src`; there certainly isn't one shown in your code.

Comment: If you want `src` to be a package, it needs to include a `__init__.py`. And to work across operating systems (many/most filesystems are case-sensitive) it needs to be named `src`, not `Src`, if that's the name you're using. Moreover, you aren't telling us which directory you're actually running this code from; if you're running it from *inside* `Src`, then that's not a package name, and you should just `from info.information import myinfo`.

Comment: (it's not common/best practice for your `src` directory to be a package; generally, someone looking at a Python source tree will expect a directory by that name to be the directory *under which packages are found*, not a package itself).

Comment: I am trying to run one of the GitHub projects where the folder structure is the same as mentioned above. @CharlesDuffy

Comment: Link us to the `setup.py` for that project, and we'll be able to see whether `src` is a package or not. If the author of that project was following best practices it's not, so you should just `from info.information import myinfo` (after installing the package with `python setup.py develop` or `python setup.py install`), not including `src` in the `import` command at all.

Comment: https://github.com/abtpst/Kaggle-IMDB

Comment: ...so they didn't even check their `setup.py` into git at all (or didn't create one in the first place)? Eww. That's sloppy maintainership on part of the project's owner.

Comment: Anyhow, if you want to use it as-is, point your `PYTHONPATH` to include `/the/path/to/Kaggle-IMDB/src`, and take `src` out of your `import` lines. Much better, though, would be to submit a PR implementing proper distutils/setuptools support.